# Converting maven artifact path to GAV with regex

Tags: regex, maven

How can I capture the below regex groups? Currently I'm capturing the GAV by normal string split.
I'm using groovy/java.

Sample input:

```
repo1-cache/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-server/7.1.0.RC1/jetty-server-7.1.0.RC1.jar
```

Sample output:

```
Group 1: org/eclipse/jetty
Group 2: jetty-server
Group 3: 7.1.0.RC1
```

Sample input 2:

```
jboss-cache/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar
```

Sample output 2:

```
Group 1: antlr
Group 2: antlr
Group 3: 2.7.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the below, which I suppose will return an Array(I dunno what's Maven) from which you can then use to access the elements.

```
/(?<=\()([^)]+(?=\))/g
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my sample input. I wanted to show the group that I wanted to grab, the input doesn't have parentheses. Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

While not using regex, you can use the same logic used by the maven indexer to parse paths to gavs. For maven 2 repositories the logic is available in the [M2GavCalculator](https://github.com/apache/maven-indexer/blob/master/indexer-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/index/artifact/M2GavCalculator.java). For maven 1 respositories the logic is available in the [M1GavCalculator](https://github.com/apache/maven-indexer/blob/master/indexer-core/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/index/artifact/M1GavCalculator.java).

You should be able to bring this into your project with:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.indexer</groupId>
  <artifactId>indexer-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```